# Spring boot 3.0.4: entity populations is no working when I retrieve from database using inmutable objects

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-3, java-17

I want to retrieve a entity after saved it in the database using inmutable objects, no getters no setters

Env.

Spring boot 3.0.4.

Java 17

Postgres 15

I try to set a inmutable entity

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "competence")
public class Competence {
private final Long id;
private fina String name;
private final LocalDatetime createdAt

Competence(Long id, String name, LocalDateTime cretedAt){
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.createdAt = createdAt;

 }

static Competence of (Long id, String name, LocalDateTime cretedAt){
   return new Competence(id, name, createdAt);
 }

    public static Competence withName(String name) {
        return new CompetenceType(
                null,
                name,
                LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

repository

```
public interface CompetenceRepository extends JpaRepository<Competence,Long> {
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/competence")
public class CompetenceTypeResource {


    private CompetenceRepository competenceRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CompetenceTypeResource(CompetenceRepository competenceRepository) {
        this.competenceRepository = competenceRepository;
    }


    @PostMapping
    public CompetenceType createcompetence(@RequestBody CompetenceTypeDTO competence) {
        CompetenceType competenceType = CompetenceType.withName(competence.name());

        return this.competenceTypeRepository.save(competenceType);
    }
}
```

I will expect a Json response with the new entity created but all I get is a empty Json `{}`

Do I need to write getters and setters?

Is there a way to populate inmutable objects in JPA?

Is there a way to populate entities without getters and setters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add getters (use `@Getter`) in order to make the fields accessible to Jackson for proper serialization. Getters don't break the immutability of an object.

Just a note that in case an entity has no getters and setters Spring JPA has a workaround: It instantiates an entity through a no-args constructor and uses reflection to access the fields. It is not the way you want to go. The entities are not meant to be immutable (from the JPA perspective). I suggest you make the immutable domain and JSON layer and map through them.